# Show the submenu on mouse over instead of mouse click in MenuBar in Flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6

I am working in Flex 4.6 web application. I have a menubar when i click on that submenu is being open after that it works on mouse over. Now the problem is I want it on mouse over when i over the mouse on menubar submenu should open not onclick. How can i do it. Please give me your advice.

Thanks
Bikrant Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MOUSE_OVER event this way

```
    <mx:MenuBar id="menuBar" creationComplete="onMenuComplete(event)" />



    private function onMenuComplete(event:FlexEvent) {
        menuBar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMenuRollOver, true);

    }

    private function onMenuRollOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
        if (event.target is IMenuBarItemRenderer && menuBar.selectedIndex == -1) {
            var index:int = IMenuBarItemRenderer(event.target).menuBarItemIndex;
            menuBar.selectedIndex = (index == 0) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
```

But if you want to hide it too, you should use MOUSE_OUT event

Comment: Thanks you so much its working file...Vasil Medvedev.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for hide this menu on MOUSE_OUT.